# Laravel DRY nested eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I got a model with a few relations:

```php
class Author extends Model
{
    public function shortStories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ShortStory::class);
    }

    public function essays()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Essay::class);
    }

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

Now suppose I got two more models that want to eager load this model with its relations:

```php
class Publisher extends Model
{
    public function scopeWithAuthor($query)
    {
        $query->with('author.shortStories', 'author.essays', 'author.books');
    }
}

class Reviewer extends Model
{
    public function scopeWithAuthor($query)
    {
        $query->with('author.shortStories', 'author.essays', 'author.books');
    }
}
```

Problem - if the relations of author change I now need to reflect this in multiple locations.

My question - how do I achieve this in DRY style?

I know that I could add a protected `$with` to the Author class but then it would always load the relation, not just when required.

With that in mind, one solution I have come up with is to extend the `Author` model like so:

```php
class AuthorWithRelations extends Author
{
    protected $with = ['shortStories', 'essays', 'books'];
}
```

This then allows me to refactor the scopes of the other models like so:

```php
class Publisher extends Model
{
    public function scopeWithAuthor($query)
    {
        $query->with('authorWithRelations');
    }
}

class Reviewer extends Model
{
    public function scopeWithAuthor($query)
    {
        $query->with('authorWithRelations');
    }
}
```

This works well enough but really I was wondering if Laravel provides a better / inbuilt approach to this?

Comment: Maybe you can extract an abstract class that just have `scopeWithAuthor` method. Or maybe a trait.

Comment: No matter what how you decide to implement this - when you call your author model, you will ultimately be deciding whether you want to have Author with or Author without relationships. You'll either be calling a different class (which would require refactoring if you changed your models' structure) or you can use the laravel native with method. If your model changes, refactoring will occur. I agree with DRY principles but this might be prematurely over optimization given that the example you give is "what if the relationship btw book and author change?" ... it hasn't changed since gutenberg.

Comment: This is just an example, my actual set of relations has nothing to do with books, this was just to simplify and demonstrate the issue at hand but thanks for your thoughts on this Can & steelman - I am getting the impression that there is no inbuilt Laravel solution to this, which is fair enough :-)